# UIImagePickerController is oversized, extending beyond screen window

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, pixate

I'm noticing in iOS8, when showing an **UIImagePicker** with a camera via modal, the edge of the screen is cut off.

**Here is a sample image (notice the 'flip' icon is cut off on the edge):**

[image]

Oddly enough, this behavior is on both iPhone 5 & iPhone 6.

I'm working with the standard `UIImagePickerController` in iOS

```
 UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.allowsEditing = NO;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is inside of another `UIViewController`, which fits just fine on the screen. I've played with some of the settings, including 'extend edges', but nothing seems to change this slight cutoff.

Has anyone experienced this, or know of a fix?

**UPDATE**

I've narrowed the cause down to Pixate's Freestyle library. Disabling the library entirely removes the issue, but deleting all of the styles in my scss files does not fix it, so it must be something deeper in Pixate, rather than a style rule.

Comment: Have you tried setting the pickers frame to the viewControllers view's frame?

Comment: @DougWatkins Just gave that a try - no luck. I also noticed the width logged as 320, which is correct. It seems like it might just be the top bar that is shifted, rather than the entire view. The flash icon seems like it's shifted over as well.

Comment: Just as an additional note, I checked the origin.x property, which is 0

Comment: Sounds weird. Did you have a look at the view hierarchy (via Xcode view debugging or something like Reveal) - just to get an idea what it could be that is wrong here...

Comment: @DanielRinser I took a look at Reveal, and it's like that button itself is in the wrong location (CAMFlipButton)